# Match two string patterns at the same time with regex for removal

Tags: javascript

A quick question for string manipulation in Javascript.

I have some files named with this pattern:

```
content_filename
content_big_filename
```

The filename is in a variable, so I cannot take the last 8 chars. 
I need to extract the filename.

Now I'm using

`string.replace( /\/content_/, '' )` but I need also to support content_big.

How should I go about this?

Comment: what u want.. extract `filename` ? can u explain?

Comment: **string.replace( /\/content_(big_)?/, '' )** will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the last part after the underscore, just split and pop

```
str.split('_').pop();
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML += "content_filename1".split('_').pop() + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += "content_big_filename2".split('_').pop()
```

Comment: smart solution but If I have some files with underscore in filename this doesn't works.

Comment: Nope, if the filename contains underscores as well, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in sequence as long as you do it in the right order.

While `content_` will match both cases, `content_big_` will only match the second case.

By looking at `content_big_` first, you won't break the `content_` check that you do subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the regex path, as demonstrated in your question, use the following.

```
string.replace( /content(_big)?_/, '' )
```

The `(some_text_here)?` (specifically the `?`) in the regex defines a block of regex that *can* match, but isn't required.

**Please note:** If regex can be avoided, it's almost always a good idea to do so. See [adeneos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29947440/1630446) for further advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1)
```

edit for explanation :

substring : extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices. If the second indice is not specified, it extracts from the indice to the end of the string.

lastIndexOf : return the indice of the last "_" character of the string.

So what you want to return is the string after the last "_" to the end of the string.

However if the "filename" contain a "_", it will not work.

Comment: It helps the OP (and indeed all other users of the site) if you explain your answer and what it does.